# Does having 1000's of CF's will lead to OOM in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am having a cluster with multiple CF's (around 1000 maybe more). And I get OOM errors time to time from different nodes. We have three Cassandra nodes? Is it an expected behavior in cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each table (columnfamily) requires a minimum of 1MB of heap memory, so it's quite possible this is causing some pressure for you.

The best solution is to redesign your application to use less tables; most of the time I've seen this it's because someone designed it to have "one table per X" where X is a customer or a data source or even a time period.  Instead, combine tables with a common schema and add a column to the primary key with the distinguishing element.

In the short term, you probably need to increase your heap size.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your feed back appreciate a lot